# The sectionView has been loaded on the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

As the picture shows. I make a tableview which can splite by inserting one row (the gray one) when I click on the cell, click again to cancel the splite:

[image]

The code is as below:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    int clickCellRow = [indexPath row] + 1;
    int clickCellSection = [indexPath section];

    [self beginUpdates];

    if (isEditFlag == NO) {
        isEditFlag = YES;
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:clickCellRow inSection:clickCellSection]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];   
}
    else {
        isEditFlag = NO;      
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:clickCellRow inSection:clickCellSection]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    [self endUpdates];
}
```

It works well on IOS6, but on IOS7 one bug happened. When one cell is clicked and the splited row is inserted, then the sectionView is forced to go outside of the screen:

[image]

After cancelling the splite, and scroll the hidden cell up. The table turn to be as below :

[image]

It seems that the sectionView has been loaded on the cell! How does this happened and how to fix it?